# onclick return error on Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: php, html, button, onclick

I have this code:

```
    <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
    <a href="home.php">Go Home</a>
    </button>
```

I want it to return a message when user clicks on that button. If they click OK then it'll direct them to home, else cancel remains.

This works on Chrome, but not on Firefox (latest version).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's probably following the default action of the link inside of your `button` element. Try `preventDefault` onclick of that link. A better question, though, is why do you have a link inside of a `button`?

Comment: Because I want to display a message onclick. I can do onclick and direct to page but I won't be able to display message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is call a function that will then redirect for you instead of trying to do it with a link. Try this:

```
<button onclick="Redirect();">Go Home</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            window.location.href = 'home.php';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew this, but is it possible to do it without JS or any script? I just want it to be as simplified as possible. But if it's not possible then this is perfect.

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want without JavaScript. In your original code `confirm('Are you sure?');` is JavaScript, just the manner in which you are using it is wrong.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know that was JS. Thought it was HTML5! But thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better approach:

#### javascript file

```
document.getElementById('gohome').addEventListener('click',
    function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        window.location="home.php";
    }
}, false);
```

#### html file

```
<button id="gohome" value="Go Home">
```

Comment: *Better* is subjective. This answer would be *better* if you simply said *"Here is an alternative approach that is unobtrusive."* Good answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is used to pass a value to the calling function. You have no calling function on a click event, therefore you do not need `return`.